# Is setting GCC_GENERATE_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS=NO the same as DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT=dwarf-with-dsym

Tags: xcode, debugging, gcc

The former seems to imply no debug symbols whereas the latter puts them in a separate file?

Sorry if this is a duplicate there weren't many posts with GCC_GENERATE_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS in them it seems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not the same.

From my understanding:

`GCC_GENERATE_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS` - controls whether debug symbols are generated.
`CLANG_DEBUG_INFORMATION_LEVEL` - controls the level of debug information generated.
`DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT` - controls the format and delivery of the debug information.

The xcode help gives more details: https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.2/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/itcaec37c2a6?sub=dev5c0105d2a